# Android JSoup editing text tag

Tags: android, html, jsoup

How can I get the text like this:

```
<body>
hi
</body>
```

and **make it bold**.
 I have tried a number of different things that have not worked, mainly because the tags I try to add with

`element.wrap();`

are added in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
    String html = "<html><body>hi</body></html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element body = doc.select("body").first();

    body.html("<b>" + body.text() + "</b>");
```

Comment: This would work well, just remember that if you have any other elements inside the body, they will be removed. If you want to preserve the tags then you use ´body.html()´ instead of body.text().

Note that this isn't valid HTML.